# Perl splitting array based on condition using grep

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I have some perl code that looks something like this:

```
my @array = map { rand } ( 1..100 );
my @matching = grep { $_ == $condition } @array;
@array = grep { $_ != $condition } @array;
```

This works ok, but what I would like to do is split the original array into two based on a single operation...I think I'm carrying out twice as many operations as strictly necessary.

Help appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By far the easiest method is to iterate your array and push values to either of the two arrays depending on the condition, as in the below example.

```
for (@array) {
  if ($_ % 2) {push @odd,  $_}
  else        {push @even, $_}
}
```

---

If you'd like to modify the source array:

```
for (my $i =0; $i < @array; ++$i) {
  if ($array[$i] % 2) {
    push @odd, splice (@array, $i--, 1);
  }
}
```

---

### Why didn't you recommend List::MoreUtils::part?

The module in question might not exists on the target system, which is always an annoying thing.

*Also on the system I ran tests on I found that `List::MoreUtils::part` was twice as slow as first snippet in this post, though with different implementations of `part` it might be the opposite actually.*

Comment: [List::MoreUtils](http://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) not existing: [Yes, even you can use CPAN](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node=Yes%2C%20even%20you%20can%20use%20CPAN) -- benchmark sounds like premature optimisation.  Code that reads like its spec is always better until you know you need something faster, and even then, can potentially be differently optimised at that time (e.g., XS?)

Comment: My testing shows part to be significantly faster when XS (169% faster - well over double), but less signifantly slower when PP (-52%, slightly less than half) w/perl 5.14.2 - pretty reasonable rates.  The bigger @array, the better `part` performs.

Comment: @Tanktalus Yeah, when using PP the custom made function is faster, though compare to XS it doesn't stand a chance. And regarding cpan, of course you can install it through `cpan`, but installing a whole module because of one function is over kill, at least if you ask me.

Comment: [Modules that depend on List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/requires/module/List::MoreUtils) Includes [Ubic](https://metacpan.org/release/Ubic) [Perl-Critic](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl-Critic) [Moose](https://metacpan.org/release/Moose) [Padre](https://metacpan.org/release/Padre) [PPI](https://metacpan.org/release/PPI) If you really use Perl to get work done, you probably already have one of these installed, so List::MoreUtils would already be installed.

Comment: @BradGilbert if you really use perl to get work done quickly and not always executing it on your own machine(s). there is a big chance it isn't there.

Answer (score 10):

This is where [`part`](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils#part-BLOCK-LIST) from [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils) comes in handy.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw'part';
my($even,$odd) = part { $_ % 2 } @array;
```

This works great if you want each element of input in exactly one array of the output.

---

If you want to possibly put them in more than one of the arrays, you have to loop over them yourself.
The best way to do that is with a [`foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loop.

```
my(@div2,@div3);
for my $elem (@array){
  push @div2, $elem unless $elem % 2;
  push @div3, $elem unless $elem % 3;
}
```

If there are a lot of similar checks you have to do, perhaps you should loop on what your testing against as-well.

```
my %div;
for my $elem (@array){
  for my $div (2,3,5,7,11,13){
    push @{ $out{$div} }, $elem unless $elem % $div;
  }
}
```

Comment: I love the indexing trick used in the PP implementation of `part`

Answer (score 3):

I love the simplicity of [`List::MoreUtils`](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMoreUtils)' `part` function:

```
sub part (&@) {
    my ($code, @list) = @_;
    my @parts;
    push @{ $parts[ $code->($_) ] }, $_  foreach @list;
    return @parts;
}
```

The resulting `@parts` array is an array of arrayrefs. `@$parts[0]` is the array of elements that returned false. `@$parts[1]` returned true.

Comment: There is one thing that I think could be added. If the return value from the code-ref could be an array. Then you could put each element in more than one of the output arrays.